# Can I invite user to login to my Heroku outside of the collaborators on the app?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, admin, super, heroku-postgres

I am new to Heroku. I need to get a dev in to make some global changes. It does not appear I can do this without an Enterprise package and was interested to confirm?

I can easily invite as collaborators to the app, but not to global access.

Appreciate the feedback.

We are having issues to generate files and it appears to be an access issue. We have more trouble shooting to do.